# How to code an SSRS invoice that paginates for multiple invoices and has two tablixs (tablii?)

Tags: reporting-services, invoice

I have a requirement to create an SSRS invoice that paginates for each invoice and contains two grids. The client needs to invoice showing the line item detail... and then below the detail they want another grid that summarizes by item class.

I'm at a loss on how to do this. I would normally use a Tablix, and page break after each invoice, but the two grid thing won't work.

Comment: wouldn't this be a simple tablix ? You would group by the invoice number and then for each Invoice group the details are shown in the detail group and all other summaires at the group level ? If I have understood you wrong.. show us with pictures of your desired result

Comment: I'd love to do that, but can't. Imagine 20 detail lines that go to 4 item classes. They want 20 lines and a total at the bottom, and then 4 lines and a total at the bottom. Two separate grids, currently.

What I can't figure out is how to have two grids, and paginate by invoice.

Comment: ok.. so I repeat my comment above.. rather than me trying to imagine it.. mock up what you want in excel or something and show us what you want and show us what your raw data looks like

Comment: I have this solved by using one Tablix and putting a subreport in the footer of the Tablix. that gives me my two grids, and the pagination.

Thanks so much for being willing to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this solved by using one Tablix and putting a subreport in the footer of the Tablix. that gives me my two grids, and the pagination. Thanks so much for being willing to help

Comment: You could have also nested your Tablixes in another Tablix.  By setting your grouping the same in both the parent and child (nested) Tablixes, you would end up with the same result.  The big benefit is that all of your report is now in one file, instead of two.